# Deploy application on different version of JDK

Tags: java, deployment

If my application is compiled and build on Java version 1.7 and I have not use any new features of Java 1.7 is it possible to deploy it on application server with Java version 1.6

Comment: Why not compile it for Java 1.6?

Comment: You can use the `-target 1.6` flag when compiling with javac

Answer (score 1):

as assylias said in the comments:

> You can use the -target 1.6 flag when compiling with javac

If you're using an IDE (NetBeans, for example) the option for the target framework would be somewhere in the project properties. In NetBeans: Right click the project -> Properties -> Libraries tab -> Java Platform.

Note, you will need the older JDK installed (and referenced) in order to be able to do this.

Comment: I don't think the older JDK is required to do that.

Comment: It would be if using the NetBeans IDE, which is why I mentioned it.